# Unable to delete a tenant due to License-based subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to delete a tenant, but I am told that I can't do this due to "License-based subscriptions"
[image]

How can I figure out which subscriptions Azure is talking about? I am not aware of any subscriptions ):

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one Azure AD tenant named **`SriAAD`** with *Azure AD Premium P2* license like below:

[image]

To know all the **licenses** that the above tenant has, you can check this: *Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Licenses -> All products*

[image]

When I try to delete this tenant without removing the licenses, I got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, cancel the subscriptions by visiting [Microsoft 365 Admin portal](https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?source=applauncher#/homepage) like this:

*Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Billing -> Your products -> Select subscription -> Cancel subscription*

[image]

Do the **same** for other subscriptions too like below:

[image]

After cancelling the subscriptions, **Subscription status** will be changed to **`Disabled`** like below:

[image]

Now, delete the above subscriptions that might take up to **24 hours** to be in effect.

You can **delete the tenant** successfully once the above operation is done.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found the "Windows Store for Business Trial" subscription at
https://portal.office.com/commerce/manage.aspx?empty=1 that is still set to active. Unfortunately I don't have permission to remove it.